# What to look for in optimizing already heavily optimized embeded C++ code in term of memory?

Tags: memory, optimization, signal-processing, reduce

What to look for to optimize heavily optimized embedded DSP code in terms of memory that is outside of the obvious? 
I need to reduce the memory by at least 10 percent.

Comment: Absent any code or other context? Hope for systems with 10% more memory before your release date?

Comment: Look in the map file for anything taking up too much space

Comment: Perhaps you can change some data types to ones taking up less space (e.g replacing doubles with floats)

Answer (score 0):

In DSP applications, the requirements for precision and/or quantization of data types and saved intermediate data can often be analysed.  If the minimum requirements are not multiples of 256 or 8-bits, it might be possible to reformat and pack the data type elements in non-byte-aligned structures or arrays to save data memory.  Of course, this comes with the trade-off of a higher computational cost and code footprint accessing said data, which may or may not be significant in your application.